# Get callstack information in CWndApp::ProcessWndProcException(CException* e, const MSG* pMsg)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, callstack

I have an application that makes extensive use of MFC. Whenever MFC internal asserts fail, my users just get an unhelpful "Encountered Improper Argument" popup. I'd like to add additional logging during these issues to better help track down the actual issue, so I want to make use of CWndApp::ProcessWndProcException.  However, I don't know how to get any information out of the exception other than "Encountered Improper Argument" which is just a default message that MFC produces. Is there a way to get call stack information (or exception origin) during this message?

Answer (score 0):

CException does not preserve the call stack information for the catch statement.

You can derive a type from CException that adds additional field for stack trace string and InnerException for the original exception, then wrap the exception-throwing code with a catch handler that rethrow your wrapper exception after stack walking.